# Formatting BinDiff results to a .txt

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin, tool-bindiff

I have been using BinDiff as a plug-in for IDA Pro. I understand it is not possible to run this plug-in via terminal/batch mode. Is there a way I can export the results to a more readable format such as a .pdf or a .txt? I need a more readable format then the .BinDiff and .BinExport formats that it generates.

Comment: Tried asking support?

Comment: Yes I sent Zynamics an email with no reply. I know they had it for BinDiff 3.0 but it would seem as if they have removed their 'Save to Log' functionality in version 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zynamics replied, they said that they removed the to text functionality as it was mostly used for debugging. However the .BinDiff results are essentially an SQLite file and can be handled as one. Firefox has a plug-in to read these SQLite files found [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/). For linux I have found that [Sqliteman](http://sqliteman.com/) works well.